# Dialog Fragment not showing up if there's a while loop

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialogfragment

I have a controller making Volley Requests, I want to block it from proceeding with the code if Internet connection is not available, thus, I designed a dialog fragment to show if Internet connection is not available, and a button to check for connection, if there's a connection, the dialog will be dismissed.

Here's my code:

```
if(!CheckInternetConnection.getInstance(context).isOnline()){
    NoInternetConnection noInternetConnection=new NoInternetConnection();
    noInternetConnection.setContext(context);
    noInternetConnection.show(fragmentManager,"NoInternetConnection");
    while (!CheckInternetConnection.getInstance(context).isOnline());
}
```

Note that, when I comment that while loop, the dialog comes up, but however I need it to check for connection

Answer (score 0):

```
    new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
            while (!CheckInternetConnection.getInstance(context).isOnline()) {
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            /*
            Call some method in the DialogFragment to dismiss it.
             */
            noInternetConnection.dismissDialog();
        }
    }.execute();
```

You should use an [AysncTaskLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) instead of an an AsyncTask so this thread dosen't get executed concurrently. Also best to wait some time inbetween each loop. I'm not sure what exactly is going on in your `CheckInternetConnection`. Cheers!